Why don't cygwin permissions simply inherit from parent folder in NTFS?
Whenever I create a new file (on NTFS) using a cygwin terminal session
the permissions do not inherit from the container, nor indeed do
they seem logical.
For instance in my windows Documents folder (C:\Users\me\Documents)
eg  echo x > x
I find that the created file has a bewildering collection of
permissions (as shown by icacls) as follows (edited computer and user name for security):

NULL SID:(DENY)(Rc,S,X,DC)
COMPUTER\me:(R,W,D,WDAC,WO)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(DENY)(S,X)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(DENY)(S,X)
COMPUTER\None:(R)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX,W)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX,W)   Everyone:(R)

None of these permissions are inherited from the container
and many of them seem redundant (eg why is it necessary to give
NULL SID a DENY ACE when the absence of any explicit allow
would cause the access to be denied anyway?)
Furthermore, when I access the security tab through windows explorer
I get the message:
"The permissions on x are incorrectly ordered which may cause some entries to be ineffective"
I am running windows 10 (22H2 19045.3693) and cygwin 3.5.3
I recognize that much thought must have gone into these ACLs
but I cannot see the logiv of them even though I am familiar
enough (or so I believe) with Microsoft's tortured security
framework as it applies to NTFS
Apologies if this is not a good forum and/or question is
too vague. I have looked at other postings in this general
subject area (eg use noacl for etc/fstab) but find they
have their own issues (eg no files are executable) or
address my confusion only tangentially

Cygwin is a POSIX layer on-top of Windows. It attempts to create a POSIX environment, similar to the Linux environment. In this case, the Windows permissions required to simulate the desired POSIX permissions may look a bit odd from the Windows point of view, but they should look and act like the expected POSIX permissions using Cygwin tools. "Fixing" the permissions to use the canonical Windows ordering will break the POSIX emulation in subtle ways.

Doug. TY for reply. I have read the cywin documentation about the ordering leading to windows complaining about it.  Ok.  But I would like to understand why the denies are in place. For instance if, within cygwin, I do chmod 755  then the denies on adminstrators and system disappear. What is the bizarrw deny on synhronization for?
